Issue while upgrading the angular version from 11 to 12
I face the issue while upgrade the angular version in my project. Currently I'm using the angular version 11 Now I want to upgrade the angular version to 12.
First I run this command:
ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12

This give me error of 'node version at least 18', so I change the node version to 18 and then install node package and then re-run the command of upgrade angular version.
After this command when I run the project this give me error like below
enter image description here
Let me know if anyone have solution for this. Thank you in advance.
I follow the angular official document to update from 11 to 12
https://angular.dev/update-guide?v=11.0-12.0&l=1

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You should take the node.js version seriously and keep it within the compatibility range as per the angular version.
I believe using the version of node 18 is giving the error "error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported"
Angular/Node.js version compatibility



Angular
Node.js
TypeScript
RxJS





15.1.x || 15.2.x
^14.20.0 || ^16.13.0 || ^18.10.0
>=4.8.2 <5.0.0
^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0



15.0.x
^14.20.0 || ^16.13.0 || ^18.10.0
~4.8.2
^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0



14.2.x || 14.3.x
^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0
>=4.6.2 <4.9.0
^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0



14.0.x || 14.1.x
^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0
>=4.6.2 <4.8.0
^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0



13.3.x || 13.4.x
^12.20.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0
>=4.4.3 <4.7.0
^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0



13.1.x || 13.2.x
^12.20.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0
>=4.4.3 <4.6.0
^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0



13.0.x
^12.20.0 || ^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0
~4.4.3
^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0



12.2.x
^12.14.0 || ^14.15.0
>=4.2.3 <4.4.0
^6.5.3 || ^7.0.0



12.1.x
^12.14.0 || ^14.15.0
>=4.2.3 <4.4.0
^6.5.3



12.0.x
^12.14.0 || ^14.15.0
~4.2.3
^6.5.3





Yes, you are right. I tried with node version 14.21.1 but It gave me a error like below
Node.js version v14.21.1 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.19.
Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

@DarshanMulani Could you defective error, try to stick to the node.js versions as per the compatibility guide, as long as the angular compiles, you do not have a problem!

@DarshanMulani Your angular cli globally should also be the same version as what you have on your project, I think that is why you are getting this error, could you please install the same version globally
